# Jmeter while condition to check values from json extractor

Tags: json, jmeter

Is there a way that I'd be able to write a condition to check and see if multiple variables match a value?

I might have n number of values from a json extractor:
color_1=green
color_2=green
...
color_n=green

And I want to somehow keep looping (whether thats with a while loop or something else) until both colors, color_1 and color_2, return green.
What would the condition for the loop look like?

Answer (score 0):

In the while controller please give the following condition,

```
${__groovy((!vars.get('color_1').equals('green') && (!vars.get('color_2').equals('green') && (vars.get('__jm__While Controller__idx') as int ) < 30),)}
```